# How do I set up a Dojo build process with multiple applications?

Tags: node.js, build, dojo

I have a single-page Dojo (1.8) application, built on top of [Colin Snover's Dojo Boilerplate](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate), and it builds and works well. Now I've expanded the website into multiple pages, some of which have other Dojo applications. It works well from the source directories, but the build process doesn't pick up the additional files and thus the installed website is broken.

I need to update the build process so that it optimizes and copies all of the files, but I can't figure out where I should be adding the additional references.

(I've gone through lots of Dojo documentation, but it tends to focus on the details of the trees, or even the tree branches, without saying just what the forest looks like.)

The original boilerplate file tree is as follows:

- /build.sh: the bash-based build script, which at its core runs the build tool under node.js
- /profiles/app.profile.js: the "application build profile", handed to the build script with the `--profile` option
- /webroot/: the root web server directory, containing:

  - /dijit/, /dojo/, /dojox/, /util/: the standard Dojo source directories
  - /app/: the application directory, containing

    - main.js: the main entry point for the app, which requires everything and then parses the DOM to instantiate the various app objects
    - run.js: some fundamental require()ments, handed to the build tool with the `--require` option
    - (the rest of the app's code)

The build tool is invoked from /webroot/util/buildscripts/ as follows:

```
node ../../dojo/dojo.js load=build --require ../../app/run.js --profile ../../../profiles/app
```

I've now added two new applications: one hosted in /webroot/info.html with source in /webroot/info/*, and the other in /webroot/licenses.html with source in /webroot/licenses/* (both apps have run.js and main.js based on the initial boilerplate files). The new apps use the various Dojo tools, as well as some of the classes in /webroot/app/*.

But, where do I add references to these new apps so that the build process Does The Right Thing? Here are some possibilities I've come up with:

- Add new `--require newApp/run.js` options to the build tool
- Add new profiles, included by additional `--profile newApp.profile.js` options to the build tool
- Add new "layers" to the existing app.profile.js file
- Run the build tool multiple times, each time configured for one of the apps, trusting it to properly merge the files into the destination directory (I doubt this would work, but I've considered it...)

So, where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

simplest is to create one bash file per application, which you can still optimize down to one via passed through bash variables from the command line ($1 $2,...).

so basically, you copy over the build.sh into each app directory, adjust the paths, and then you create a master shell script, calling each app's build.sh

Comment: So, you build the apps individually, and then merge the file trees? I'm pretty sure that there are files that would appear in multiple apps, but with different contents, so I don't think that would work.